# Change Paper Size in Tufte Book Class

Tags: paper-size, tufte

Is there a (relatively) easy way to change the paper size in the tufte-book class? The manual for Tufte 3.50 by Kevin Godby (http://kevin.godby.org/2009/12/11/tufte-latex-350-released/) says,

"To specify a different paper size (and/or margins) use the `\geometrysetup` command in the preamble of your document (or one of the file hooks). The full documentation of the `\geometrysetup` command can be found in the `geometry` package documentation."

The 2008 version of the documentation, by Hideo Umeki, is referenced. This version has been superseded by the 2010 `geometry` package documentation, which contains no mention of the `\geometrysetup` command (at least, "find `\geometrysetup`" and "find setup" turned up nothing, while searches for other commands yielded results).

So how can the page size be changed using the tufte book class?

To add a MWE, the papersize remains the default 8.5x11.5 despite the addition of the `geometry` package and the `\geometry` command.

```
\documentclass{tufte-book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{geometry}

 \geometry{height=9in,width=6in}

\newenvironment{loggentry}[2]% date, heading
{\noindent\textbf{#2}\marginnote{#1}\\}{\vspace{0.5cm}}

\begin{document}


\begin{loggentry}{2009-Oct-31}{Snow}
\lipsum[1]
\end{loggentry}

\begin{loggentry}{2010-Dez-31}{Water of Life}
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

The answer was provided in the comments but I don't know how to mark it as correct. Thank you everyone.

Comment: I think what you need is the `\geometry` command. I still have the TeXLive DVD from 2008 and there is no `\geometrysetup` command in that version of `geometry`. Perhaps the instructions meant to use two words: "the `\geometry` setup command"

Comment: Dan is correct. It should be `\geometry` instead of `\geometrysetup`. I apologize for the typo. The Tufte-LaTeX document classes use the `geometry` package for adjusting the margins and page layout. You can use any of the facilities provided by that package to make the modifications you desire.

Comment: Check the MWE: the output is still 8.5x11.5, though geometry specifies 6x9. Because...??

Comment: @user26732 You have only set `\textwidth` and `\textheigh` by options `width` and `height`. Therefore you need to set options `paperwidth` and `paperheight`.

Comment: @TeXnician I have now written an answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Options `width` and `height` of `\geometry` set the width and height of the text body (`\textwidth` and `\textheight`). Options `paperwidth` and `paperheight` sets the paper or media size, e.g.:

Most of the following settings are scaled values according to the settings for B5 in `tufte-common.def`. The margin par area is made smaller to follow the width of the dates.

```
\documentclass{tufte-book}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{geometry}

\makeatletter
% Patch to ignore warnings
\Gm@hbodyfalse
\Gm@vbodyfalse
\makeatother

\geometry{
  % showframe,
  paperwidth=6in,
  paperheight=9in,
  left=0.55in,
  right=0.45in,
  top=.5in,
  bottom=.5in,
  marginparsep=0.25in,
  marginparwidth=0.65in,
  includemp,
  includehead,
  % The text width and height are calculated automatically.
}

\newenvironment{loggentry}[2]% date, heading
{\noindent\textbf{#2}\marginnote{#1}\\}{\vspace{0.5cm}}

\begin{document}
\begin{loggentry}{2009-Oct-31}{Snow}
\lipsum[1]
\end{loggentry}

\begin{loggentry}{2010-Dez-31}{Water of Life}
\lipsum[2]
\end{loggentry}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

For layout experiments, option `showframe` for `geometry` is useful:

> [image: Result with option showframe]